# Convergence rate for such modified method of steepest descent

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

We consider only the quadratic case. $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}x^TQx. $ And suppose we can choose $x_0$ to make $g_0$ in the span of its eigenvectors $e_i$, where $g_k=Qx_k$, being the gradient in each iteration.

I have already showed that each $g_k$ is also in the span of the eigenvectors. And in a special case where $g_0$ equals some eigenvector, it will converge in the next step. But for more general case, the calculation got messy.

Here I followed the theorem from "Nonlinear programming" Luenberger and Ye, 4th edition, [here](https://grapr.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/luenberger-linear-and-nonlinear-programming-3e-springer-2008.pdf), section 8.6. The convergence rate is given by $1-\frac{(g_k^Tg_k)^2}{(g_k^TQg_k)(g_k^TQ^{-1}g_k))}$. When $g_0$ is an eigenvector, just by calculation, it is zero. But what about in general it is in the span of eigenvectors?

Any hints would be appreciated.